# SMS not working from MBP with Yosemite and iOS 8

Tags: messages, ios, sms, macos

I have updated my mid 2012 MBP to yosemite, and my iPhone 5s is running iOS 8.0.

My wife called me last night, and sure enough the call popped up on my MBP. I answered the call, and it works fine.

**The problem is with SMS.** 
Incomming SMS do not come to my MBP. I am also unable to send messages VIA SMS to my android friends. Is there something special I have to do to make SMS work? I'll remind you that the phone call feature works fine, so I'm not sure why SMS doesn't,.

Notes:
I am on the same wifi network with both of my devices.
I have both devices loaded with most current updates.
I have bluetooth enabled on both devices.
They are within 2 feet of eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [blog post](http://iphone.appleinsider.com/articles/14/10/17/yosemite-updaters-will-need-to-wait-for-mondays-ios-81-launch-for-sms-relay-instant-hotspot?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter/) sms relay will be available with iOS 8.1